# problem on application of schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let, $D=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}$. Which are correct?

1. there exists a holomorphic function $f:D \to D$ with $f(0)=0$ & $f'(0)=2$.
2. there exists a holomorphic function $f:D \to D$ with $f(\dfrac{3}{4})=\dfrac{3}{4}$ & $f'(\dfrac{2}{3})=\dfrac{3}{4}$.
3. there exists a holomorphic function $f:D \to D$ with $f(\dfrac{3}{4})=-\dfrac{3}{4}$ & $f'(\dfrac{3}{4})=-\dfrac{3}{4}$
4. there exists a holomorphic function $f:D \to D$ with $f(\dfrac{1}{2})=-\dfrac{1}{2}$ & $f'(\dfrac{1}{4})=1$.

i saw the answer for this problem on stackexchange and understood it pretty well
but,one of my friend gave the same answer using the following argument:

take holomorphic function to be of form f(z)=az+b where a and b are complex numbers.

now,put f(0)=0 and derivative at 0 as 2 we get, f(z)=2z

now, $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ $\lt 2$ ,so im(f) not lies in open unit disk so there does not exists any holomorphic function and the answers obtained by him are correct

Is this way of approaching these problems correct??

Comment: Not all holomorphic functions are of the form $z \mapsto az + b$.

Comment: @daniel fischer:that means this approach is completely wrong...but would this be correct if f(z)=az+b satisfying the conditions exists but im(f) may lie outside open unit disk

Comment: It's one of the conditions that $f(D) \subseteq D$. Disregarding that condition, for every triple $c,d,w$ there is exactly one function of the form $f \colon z \mapsto az+b$ with $f(w) = c$ and $f'(w) = d$. But even when there is a holomorphic $g\colon D \to D$ with $g(w) = c$ and $g'(w) = d$, it's rarely the affine $f$.